# Multiple Regression: Help me understand this why the significance of independent variables "flip"

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I have roughly the following model I want to regress:

$Y = \alpha + \beta_1 * A + \beta_2 * B + \epsilon$

Where:

- $A$ is the variable I want to figure out the effect on Y of.
- $B$ is a bunch of control variables (always the same)

Now I have two different options for $A$ – let's say $A_1$ and $A_2$.
They are both proxies for what I'd optimally want $A$ to be and therefore correlated.

So I have three different models:

1. $Y = \alpha + \beta_{1_1} * A_1 + \beta_4 * B + \epsilon$
2. $Y = \alpha + \beta_{2_2} * A_2 + \beta_4 * B + \epsilon$
3. $Y = \alpha + \beta_{1_3} * A_1 + \beta_{2_3} * A_2 + \beta_{3}( A_1 * A_2)   + \beta_4 * B + \epsilon$

Now, when I run the multiple regression:

1. $\beta_{1_1}$ is not significant
2. $\beta_{2_2}$ is highly significant (p<0.01)
3. $\beta_{1_3}$ and the interaction term $\beta_{3}$ are significant (p<0.05), **but** $\beta_{2_3}$ is no longer significant

This, to me, makes no sense. It would make sense if in 3. $\beta_{2_3}$ and the interaction were significant. But in my results, the significance "flip".
Why is this? What does it tell me about the different models?

(The adj. $R^2$ is somewhat similar in all models.)

Comment: In 2., do you mean $\beta_1$ is highly significant? You are mixing the coefficients between variables which creates some confusion. I would use $\beta_1$ for A1, $\beta_2$ for A2, and $\beta_4$ for the other variables in all cases.

Comment: Yes, sorry – this was unfortunate. 
I did it the way you suggested and also added a second subscript to indicate which model I'm referring to. (E.g $\beta_{2_3}$ relates to $A_2$ in model 3.)

Comment: I would pay no attention to p-values in model (3) due to the intrinsic multicollinearity.  In short, what you observe is predictable and therefore tells you nothing about your data.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Do you have a resource I can study for why it's predictable?
How do I deal with my Null Hypothesis in the model with interaction terms, if I can't rely on p-values (and therefore presumably also not on the standard errors)?